# Using 'AND' in SQL WHERE clause for the same filed

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the scenario. I have 1 table that has all the contact details. Another table that has all the list of Categories. And a 3rd table which is an associate table, that has the ID of the first table and the ID of the second table.

This is how my associate table looks like

**contactdid** -2 |  **categoryid** -1

**contactdid** -2 |  **categoryid** -2

**contactdid** -2 |  **categoryid** -3

**contactdid** -3 |  **categoryid** -1

**contactdid** -3 |  **categoryid** -3

This is my SQL code below(Generated using SQLyog and i included the where clause).

```
SELECT
    press_contacts.email
FROM
    contacts_category
    INNER JOIN press_category 
        ON (contacts_category.categoryid = press_category.id)
    INNER JOIN press_contacts 
        ON (contacts_category.contactdid = press_contacts.id)
WHERE contacts_category.categoryid = 1 AND contacts_category.categoryid = 2 ;
```

I get the output when I do not have `AND contacts_category.categoryid = 2`inserted in the code.

Any idea how to solve this.I clearly have data.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: how the category id hold two values at once it is not possible with the AND but with OR
for AND operator to return a row it is necessary that both the expressions should evaluate to true but in your case it's never as far as i understand  your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to see those email addresses with contacts in both categories, try:

```
SELECT press_contacts.email
FROM contacts_category
    INNER JOIN press_contacts 
        ON (contacts_category.contactdid = press_contacts.id)
WHERE contacts_category.categoryid in (1, 2)
GROUP BY press_contacts.email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT contacts_category.categoryid)=2
```

Comment: I was wondering what if i had 3 ID's like "WHERE contacts_category.categoryid in (1, 2, 3)" , what will be the id give for the "HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT contacts_category.categoryid)=??"

Comment: For three different categories, `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT contacts_category.categoryid)=3` . Unless you wanted at least two out of three, in which case `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT contacts_category.categoryid)>=2` .

Answer (score 5):

contacts_category.categoryid can not be 1 and 2 at the same time, perhabs you mean OR instead of AND?

Comment: My requirement is to retrieve emails of those who are in both categories 1 and 2

Answer (score 3):

Use `OR` or `IN()` instead of `AND`.
A field can't have two values at the same time